# "Satisfaction of atomic constraint depends on itself" error, but only on friend functions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts, friend-function

I am attempting to create a class that wraps another template-specified type, like a `Box`. I also want to add operators to enable comparing `Box`('s stored value) against any type that its stored value is comparable to. A `requires` clause is used to check that the comparison is valid. Here is a simple example:

```cpp
template <class T> struct Box {
    T val;
    
    template <class... Args> Box(Args&&... args)
        : val(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    
    template <class O> bool operator==(const O& b) const
        requires requires { val == b; } { return val == b; }
};

int main() {
    Box<int> a(5);
    a == 5;
}
```

This compiles and runs fine with `operator==` as a member function. However, if I rewrite the `operator==` as a friend function, it falls apart:

```cpp
//...
    template <class O> friend bool operator==(const Box& a, const O& b)
        requires requires { a.val == b; } { return a.val == b; }
//...
```

When compiled on GCC:

```cpp
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class O> bool operator==(const Box<int>&, const O&) requires requires{operator==::a->val == operator==::b;} [with O = int]':
<source>:14:29:   required by substitution of 'template<class O> bool operator==(const Box<int>&, const O&) requires requires{operator==::a->val == operator==::b;} [with O = int]'
<source>:20:7:   required from here
<source>:13:33:   required by the constraints of 'template<class T> template<class O> bool operator==(const Box<T>&, const O&) requires requires{operator==::a->val == operator==::b;}'
<source>:14:12:   in requirements  [with T = int; O = Box<int>]
<source>:14:26: error: satisfaction of atomic constraint 'requires{operator==::a->val == operator==::b;} [with T = T; O = O]' depends on itself
   14 |                 requires requires { a.val == b; } { return a.val == b; }
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This appears on all the most recent versions of GCC, in both C++20 and C++23 modes. Clang gives a similar error. The same problem also occurs (albeit with a longer error message) if I use a concept instead of a `requires` expression, such as `std::equality_comparable_with`. The only way to fix this error is to not check the validity of the comparison expression in the `requires` clause.

It seems that the compiler is considering the enclosing operator function in the overload set of the `requires` constraint, causing the operator to be infinitely instantiated recursively. But I don't quite get how that is possible? I thought friend functions could only be found by ADL, and neither of the operands in the `requires` expression is a `Box` (in this instantiation, both are `int`), which should additionally fail due to type argument mismatch, and the fact that `int` doesn't have a member `val` (after the first recursion). Can someone explain what is going on, and if possible, how this can be fixed?

Comment: Since `Box`'s constructor is not constrained, it can be implicitly constructed by `int`, which allows the template parameter `O` to be instantiated as `Box<int>`. In the `requires`-clause, we check if a `Box` can be compared with an `int`, which again instantiates `O` as `Box<int>`, and then we enter the `requires`-clause to check again...

Comment: The error occurs even if the constructor is explicit. Besides, why would the compiler deduce O as `Box<int>` over `int` when the argument is `int`?

Comment: "*The error occurs even if the constructor is explicit.*" Probably a bug of gcc, [clang works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/9bYY3jYhM).